# Does underscore signify a function call?

Tags: syntax

What is the `_` used to signify when following some sequence like `\hat`?  The error I sometimes get leads me to wonder if it represents a function call, with whatever follows it being the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

`_` (in math mode) identifies "subscript notation"; similarly `^` identifies "superscript notation".

From the [TeX Book](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (**Chapter 16: Typing Math Formulas**, p 128):

> ... you can get superscripts <sup>(up high)</sup> and subscripts <sub>(down low)</sub> by using `^` and `_`, as shown in the following examples:
>
> Input  ->  Output
> `$x^2$` -> x<sup>2</sup>
> `$x_2$` -> x<sub>2</sub>
> `$2^x$` -> 2<sup>x</sup>
> `$x^2y^2$` -> x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>
> `$x ^ 2y ^ 2$` -> x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>
> `$x_2y_2$` -> x<sub>2</sub>y<sub>2</sub>
> `$_2F_3$` -> <sub>2</sub>F<sub>3</sub>
>
> Notice that `^` and `_` apply only to the next single character. If you want several things to be superscripted or subscripted, just enclose them in braces.

In case these are used with *operators* (like `\int`, and `\sum`, ...), they may be set slightly differently when used in a display.

Comment: As we know, DEK doesn't always quite tell the truth :-) Assuming `_` is catcode 8 then it will work with certain unbraced content.

Comment: For instance, `$x_ \relax\space\relax\bgroup 2\egroup$` is equivalent to `$x_2$`. But this is going esoteric. `;-)`